# Get Data Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Functions script for sending a notification to the admin of a Firebase App whenever a user sends anything to the Database. The only issue that I am having with this script is that the FCM Identifier of the admin might change at some point and I want to make sure that the notifications are sent after that change. To do this, I need to get the notificationID attribute from the /Admin/ location and then send a notification to that ID.

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userUid}/').onWrite(event => {

    const userUid = event.params.userUid;

    const payload = {
      notification: {
        body: 'New Update Received',
        badge: '1',
        sound: 'default',
      }
    };

    const token = '***********:APA91bEinTuLWRmOZuS0SswU7r59hhRQCFzCXOuE7qs4vlddkNLCbtSPJlhaQny44QpZQcWMmJqr8IJpW2Tk2gndosXF6DP6iBLSqzZG5IUkyoDNw0JjCNTJ-cHVV3-fs5i2MtBnx9aB';
```

I need to replace the following const token line with something that will get the notificationID from my Firebase Database.

```
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {

        console.log('Notification Sent');

    });

});
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thanks

KPS

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once for how to read from the database with the Admin SDK

Comment: But that's for Node.js, my file is in JavaScript

Comment: Cloud Functions *are* node programs. In Cloud Functions for Firebase, you use the Admin SDK to access the database. The functions-samples all auto-import the `admin` module for you, so that you can get started straight way.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.